# Tableau Dashboard does not render data in “:embed=y” mode, when using Username()

Tags: tableau-api

We have a sample worksheet, working off some data source like sample superstore (for example sake)

We use another data source like user_details which has data like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Allow</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>R4****3</td>
    <td>Vivek</td>
    <td>Y</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>F5****8</td>
    <td>Srinivasan</td>
    <td>N</td>
  </tr>  
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

We blend this user_details data with superstore data to filter not allowed users, by data blending and adding a calculated field, which has a formula:

```
IF [ID] == USERNAME() AND [Allow] == 'Y'    
THEN 1    
ELSE 0    
END
```

As a result of this when we switch to Vivek I can see data in tableau desktop.

But we cannot see data when I switch to Srinivasan in tableau desktop.

When push these to changes to server, in normal mode it works fine, but when we clear all browser cache and cookies, and use tableau URL parameter -> “?:embed=y” the view does not load data for the user Vivek.

https://community.tableau.com/message/612072#612072

[Attached is the workbook and issue detail for reference here](https://community.tableau.com/message/612072#612072)

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having a Tableau Server instance to test on right now, my first guess for why this is failing when using `?:embed=y`is because you have a core license with the guest account enabled.

If that is the case, then disabling the guest account should resolve the issue since whoever views the workbook will be prompted to log in and thus the USERNAME() function will work as expected.

If a core license and guest account is not in use, and Vivek logs in to view the embedded workbook but is still unable to view data as expected, then that sounds like a matter for Tableau Support to assist with.

Comment: This was exactly the issue, I have a core base license. When I followed up with Tableau they recommended turning off Guest access, and that resolved the issue.
Any reason why ?:embed uses guest as default?

Comment: Yes. The idea is that customers might want to embed views in an externally facing web portal so that external users are also able to interact with the view. If you plan to use the guest user in such a way, then it's possible to enable/disable the guest user for specific sites (from version 10.0 onwards), or to explicitly restrict the guest user's permissions on workbooks (for this, we always recommend group and project based permissions).